# How do I change Dash elements' content without using callbacks?

Tags: plotly-dash

Suppose I have a layout which includes some element, say DataTable. How do I update its value without using callbacks?

Comment: You could also update it directly with Javascript, but can you explain why you don't want to use callbacks and what you want to do in general?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I want to have a separate thread for heavy calculations and output intermediate results from it. I know I can use dash's interval callback to regularly fetch the data but it's inconvenient.

Comment: [Client side callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) might be more appropriate in that case.